# Dramatic drop in admob banner ad fill rate post fix for ad policy violation

Tags: android, admob

A few days back my android app (with content rating of 3+) was suspended due to Ad Policy Violation.
I then made 2 changes - 
1. Added the following code to my AdRequest.Builder() - extras.putString("max_ad_content_rating", "G");
2. From AdMob - Blocking Controls, went to Sensitive Categories and Blocked 6 categories like Gambling, Drugs, Black Magic, etc, which seemed inappropriate for a 3-4 year old to be shown to.

My fill rate for banner ads has plunged from an average of 85%before the changes to 35% after, going as low as 20% on some days and a max of 65% on 1 particular day.

My question is - have I gone overboard with the changes I made? Is it better to adopt another approach, whether with the content rating of my app or something else?

Comment: Question, what kind of app is this? And also did you mark your app as “designed for family” or “audience under 13” checkbox ?

Comment: Also what did the email from google say? Sometimes they will give instructions on what changes you have to make

Comment: Yup, late reply but yes, my app is rated as 3+. The fill rate recovered although never went back to the original levels, so I guess things are as they should be.